# Android Imagery - Gallery scales

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, material-design

Using RecyclerView with a GridLayout how do i achieve this effect?
[image]

I will receive multiple images from a JSON API and i want some of then to fill the entire grid following google specs: "Within a gallery context, introduce thumbnails of various sizes to convey content hierarchy."

Comment: Inside you recyclerview's adapter you can bind different layout to have different sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` to your `RecyclerView` with gap strategy. This [strategy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html#GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS) will be used how the spaces between spans will be filled.